# How do I link the following sentences. He is a social worker. He is a teacher

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

How should I link these sentences?

> He is a social worker. He is a teacher.

I think the correct answer is

> Besides being a social worker he is also a teacher.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the two instances of *he* refer to the same person, and you do not want to imply a contrast or focus on one job over the other, it's as simple as:

> "He is a social worker **and** a teacher."

If people already know about one, but not the other (for example, in an article that introduces him as a social worker, and later introduces the fact that he is also a teacher), you might use a range of other things:

> "**As well as** being a social worker, he is **also** a teacher."
>
> "**Besides** being a social worker, he is **also** a teacher."
>
> "He is a teacher **as well as** a social worker."
>
> "He isn't **just** a social worker; he's a teacher **as well**."

There's a lot of stylistic choices to be made, but if all you want to do is deliver the two bits of information in your question, it's simplest to go with the simple '*and*' sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be "Besides being a teacher he is also a social worker."

It actually depends on which profession is the full time one. I have assumed teaching as 'his' full-time profession and gave it preference over the social work job.

Comment: Is the comma at the end of "Besides being a teacher," necessary? I wonder what happens with it removed. :)

Comment: There is also nothing wrong with *he is a social worker and a teacher*.